# Swift: Load JSON from a url and store in cache or file system

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently in the process of writing an iOS APP that downloads information from an API in JSON format then displays it in the app.

One of the key features to this app is it being able to work offline as well as online, for this reason there should be a cached version as well as an online version.

After reading through the internet to my shock I have not found any examples what so ever of this approach.

The only thing I have found that's even come close to this is HanekeSwift but the documentation seems incomplete and there is no way to clear the cache and i'm not even sure if this is a memory based cache or a filesystem based cache.

Since there is lots of ways out there to do this, core data, file system frameworks etc.. I'm not sure which one would be the best to go for, theoretically to break down my thought process all I need to do is:

- Check if the JSON file exists on the system
- If not download it from the network and store it for later use (Preferably as a string format)
- If file exists load it into a swiftyJSON object

I feel like core data would be overkill, I feel like the file system way is dated as most of the filesystem cocoa pods/libraries don't seem to be compatible with the current swift version (2.3)

Can anyone share some light on what the generic standard way of doing this is or what option would be the most suitable for my purpose of use and why.

Kindest regards

Answer (score -1):

SwiftifyJSON makes objects that support archiving. 
Try this

```
class HSCache: NSObject {

 static var defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults()


class func cacheThis(key: String, object : AnyObject) {
    defaults.setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(object), forKey: key)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
class func getFromCache(key: String, type : AnyClass) -> AnyClass? {
    if defaults.objectForKey(key) != nil {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(defaults.objectForKey(key) as! NSData) as? AnyClass
    }
    return nil
}

class func deleteFromCache(key: String) {
    defaults.removeObjectForKey(key)
    defaults.synchronize()
}

}
```